# Elegant array transformation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What's an elegent way  - purely functional, ideally - to transform (reduce?) this array:

```
var in = [
  { a: 1, b: 'x', c: 'foo' },
  { a: 1, b: 'y', c: 'goo' },
  { a: 2, b: 'x', c: 'hoo' },
  { a: 2, b: 'y', c: 'joo' }
]
```

Into this:

```
var out = [
  { a: 1, x: 'foo', y: 'goo' },
  { a: 2, x: 'hoo', y: 'joo' }
]
```

The logic is that all elements should be joined based on their `a` property, and all `b` and `c` properties denote key/value pairs respectively that should be merged into the single object based on their shared `a` value.

Comment: you want the last element in the set of all elements with the same `a` value?

Comment: What is logic to derive `out`? Note, `in` throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in`

Comment: I described the logic in my question, sorry for not stating that upfront.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a hash object, and `reduce` to wrap the hashing like this:

```js
const arr = [
  { a: 1, b: 'x', c: 'foo' },
  { a: 1, b: 'y', c: 'goo' },
  { a: 2, b: 'x', c: 'hoo' },
  { a: 2, b: 'y', c: 'joo' }
];

let result = Object.values(             // the result is the values of the hash object
  arr.reduce((hash, o) => {             // hash is a hash object that make it easier to group the result
    hash[o.a] = hash[o.a] || {a: o.a};  // if there is no object in the hash that have the value of the key a equal to o.a, then create a new one
    hash[o.a][o.b] = o.c;               // set the value of the key stored in o.b to o.c
    return hash;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `forEach` really isn't purely functional. The `reduce` is the way to go.

Comment: @Bergi I've been hesitating. I'll remove the first and keep the second. It's more _elegant_ and that's what OP is asking for!

Comment: Now  for *that* you'll get a +1 :D

Comment: Just a note on `Object.values` compatability, it's ES2017 so before using it make sure it's supported in your environments. Great answer otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a closure with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var input = [{ a: 1, b: 'x', c: 'foo' }, { a: 1, b: 'y', c: 'goo' }, { a: 2, b: 'x', c: 'hoo' }, { a: 2, b: 'y', c: 'joo' }],
    output = input.reduce((map => (r, o) => (!map.has(o.a) && map.set(o.a, r[r.push({ a: o.a }) - 1]), map.get(o.a)[o.b] = o.c, r))(new Map), []);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach` and `Object.assign` to group by `a` and then `map` to return object values.

```js
var data = [
  { a: 1, b: 'x', c: 'foo' },
  { a: 1, b: 'y', c: 'goo' },
  { a: 2, b: 'x', c: 'hoo' },
  { a: 2, b: 'y', c: 'joo' }
]

var r = {}
data.forEach(e => r[e.a] = Object.assign((r[e.a] || {}), {a: e.a, [e.b]: e.c}))
r = Object.keys(r).map(e => r[e])

console.log(r)
```

Comment: And note that `Object.assign((r[e.a] || {}), {a: e.a, [e.b]: e.c})` can be slightly shortened to `{...(r[e.a] || {}), ...{a: e.a, [e.b]: e.c}}` using object spread notation (and possibly Babel if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if approach is elegant or functional, though returns expected result using `for..of` loops, `Array.prototype.some()` and `Object.assign()`

```js
function props(array, key, prop1, prop2) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let obj of array) {
    let o = {};
    for (let {[key]:_key, [prop1]:_prop1, [prop2]:_prop2} of [obj]) {
      o[_prop1] = _prop2;
      o[key] = _key;
    }
    if (!arr.some(p => p[key] === o[key])) arr.push(o);
    for (let prop of arr) {
      if (prop[key] == o[key]) {
        prop = Object.assign(prop, o)
      }
    }
  }
  return arr
}

var _in = [
  { a: 1, b: 'x', c: 'foo' },
  { a: 1, b: 'y', c: 'goo' },
  { a: 2, b: 'x', c: 'hoo' },
  { a: 2, b: 'y', c: 'joo' }
];

console.log(props(_in, "a", "b", "c"));
```

Comment: No, that's not functional at all. And `for (let {[key]:_key, [prop1]:_prop1, [prop2]:_prop2} of [obj]) {` is just insane.

Answer (score 0):

I like provided answers, but here is my attempt. I believe it's more readable, but it uses `Object.assign` and `Object.values`

```
const input = [
  { a: 1, b: 'x', c: 'foo' },
  { a: 1, b: 'y', c: 'goo' },
  { a: 2, b: 'x', c: 'hoo' },
  { a: 2, b: 'y', c: 'joo' }
]

const map = input.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const [a, key, value] = Object.values(obj)
  const newObj = {a, [key]: value}

  if (acc[a]) {
    Object.assign(acc[a], newObj)
  } else {
   acc[a] = newObj
  }

  return acc 
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(map))
```